# AppCompatTextView gravity center not working in android 20 (KitKat)

Tags: android, android-layout, androidx

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_security_code"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/iv_security_code"
            app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/ic_refresh_black_24dp"
            android:gravity="center" />
```

This issue comes in android 20 version **(KitKat)** and working fine for **Lolipop** version devices.

Issue is, the tag **android:gravity="center"** is not working as expected. Check this image : 
[image]

Got the hack to fix this issue: After changing `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to some particular height and then it works. But still, this issue needs to be fixed.

Comment: make your view width match parent.

Comment: Can you please replace you image with any default small image, might be your image height is very large

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case, you should make the height of the textView to `match_parent`.

If you don't want to do that, you should then set the `layout_gravity="center"`.

Answer (score -1):

Hey if you want the view on the center then use `android:layout_gravity="center"`
and if you want to center the text then use `android_gravity="center"`

Comment: Yes. But I want the text to be in the center. Nothing to do with android:layout_gravity and android:gravity is not working.

Comment: will you tell me which parent view you are using or can you share the xml file here so that i can find the issue